# Prove that $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$ is irreducible in Q[X]

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Can someone please help me to prove this:

Prove that $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$ is irreducible in Q[X]

Comment: As a hint, prove that the evaluation $x\mapsto x+a$ preserves irreducibility. Then with a careful choice of $a$, use Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: This is a *cyclotomic polynomial*.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "horizontally translating" a polynomial in $R[t]$ does not change it's zeros  that is, replacing $x$ with $x+k$ for some $k\in R$ where $R$ is a commutative ring.

Baring that in mind, we have

$1+(x+1)+(x+1)^2+(x+1)^3+(x+1)^4+(x+1)^5+(x+1)^6$

is equal to

$x^6+7x^5+21x^4+35x^3+35x^2+21x+7$
of which Eisenstein's critereon applies to taking $q=7$.